# How to update a local package in visual studio code for Flutter

Tags: visual-studio-code, flutter, package

I have a Flutter project that uses a local package. When ever I update the local package I need to restart the main projects vs code instance otherwise it will not "see" the new code from intellisense etc.

```
flutter packages get
```

and

```
flutter clean
```

do not help. How to do this?

Comment: did you use version or path to indicate your local package ?

Comment: I use a local path to indicate my package

Comment: I have the same problem, do you found any solution to this?